# How to stop service after using onstartcommand?

Tags: android

How can I let my service stop when using the `onStartCommand` method?

I know I have to use `stopService()` but then Eclipse is giving me an error.

I have this code so far:

```
    package be.pegus.classapp;

    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class ClassService extends Service {
    private static String tag = "something";
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return Log.d(tag, "k");
    }



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(tag, "destroy");
}
```

Comment: The error is that inside the onstartcommand stopService() is not recognized. The "k" should be "service started"

Comment: Use Handlers inside the onStartCommand

Answer (score 4):

You may try call `stopSelf();` inside **onStartCommand** method to finish your service. This will not require you to provide the `Intent` meant for service.

Comment: Yes, call `stopSelf()` in your `onStartCommand()`, followed by `return START_NOT_STICKY`

Comment: @AlexanderFarber You don't need to bother with return type, since you are stopping the service deliberately. Returning a specific return type is useful in cases when a service is destroyed by the system (e.g. due to low memory).

Comment: I don't agree with you, because: in the original source code the author of the question returns `Log.d()` call result in `onStartCommand()` - which is nonsense. Would he return a sensible value, then it would be `START_STICKY`, `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` or `START_NON_STICKY`. Then, if he calls `stopSelf()`at some condition in `onStartCommand()`, then most probably he does not want the Android system to restart his service after low memory condition is gone.

Comment: If the returned type is not from the defined values (like the ones you mentioned), then I think the default `START_STICKY` is used. However, all I'm saying is, you don't need to worry about return value when calling `stopSelf` at any point in the service. Thus your statement **followed by return START_NOT_STICKY** will not pose any effect since the service is being stopped.

Comment: I mean the situation, when Android gets low on memory **between** the call to `stopSelf()` and `return`.